# How would I batch add a ton of jquery scripts with only one minor difference in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Here's the code I have. Basically I'm figuring the blur for a ton of images based on the position of the mouse and the scroll position. I want to do this with like 100 images but I don't want to have to copy this script 100 times just to change the the following:

```
var offset[x] = $('#img[x]').offset();
```

and then the formulas:

```
'filter': 'blur(' + ((Math.abs(offset[x].top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)',
```

And so on.

Would I be able to do this in a loop?

Here's what I have currently.

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    var offset1 = $("#img1").offset();
    var offset2 = $("#img2").offset();
    $("div.c").html(Math.abs(offset1.top - e.pageY));
    $('#img1').css({
        'filter': 'blur(' + ((Math.abs(offset1.top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)',
            '-webkit-filter': 'blur(' +((Math.abs(offset1.top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)',
            '-moz-filter': 'blur(' +((Math.abs(offset1.top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)',
            '-o-filter': 'blur(' + e.pageY - offset1.top + 'px)',
            '-ms-filter': 'blur(' + ((Math.abs(offset1.top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)'
    });
    $('#img2').css({
        'filter': 'blur(' + ((Math.abs(offset2.top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)',
            '-webkit-filter': 'blur(' +((Math.abs(offset2.top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)',
            '-moz-filter': 'blur(' +((Math.abs(offset2.top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)',
            '-o-filter': 'blur(' + e.pageY - offset2.top + 'px)',
            '-ms-filter': 'blur(' + ((Math.abs(offset2.top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)'
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you use a class selector, you can easily do this.  Please add sample html.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    $( "img" ).each(function( index ) {
      // Do it for each image
      var currentImage = $(this);
      var offset = currentImage.offset();

      currentImage.css({
         'filter': 'blur(' + ((Math.abs(offset.top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)',
         '-webkit-filter': 'blur(' +((Math.abs(offset.top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)',
         '-moz-filter': 'blur(' +((Math.abs(offset.top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)',
         '-o-filter': 'blur(' + e.pageY - offset.top + 'px)',
        '-ms-filter': 'blur(' + ((Math.abs(offset.top - e.pageY) - 30) / 20) + 'px)'
      });
    });
});
```

Instead of select one image using its #ID you can select all images directly or add a class to the ones you want to select and use .each() to iterate over all selected elements.

Comment: I understand what you are saying to do, but the implementation seems to blur all the images together regardless of their offset.